# Rails: create a method for a class that needs information from members of its own class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, model

I was wondering if it's possible to do something like follows:

Let's say I have a Rails model, `Foo`, with a database attribute `value`. `Foo` belongs_to `Bar`, `Bar` has_many `Foos`.

In my model, I'd like to do something like:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :bar

  def self.average
    # return the value of all foos here
  end

end
```

Ideally I'd like to have this method return a value that matched the scope from which it was called, so that:

```
Foo.average # would return the average value of all foos

@bar = Bar.find(1)
@bar.foos.average # would return the average of all foos where bar_id == 1
```

Can such a thing be done, and if so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have will work as is, as long as you make sure to call methods on `self` instead of `Foo` in the body of the `average` method. When calling methods on a scope of `Foo`, `self` in the body of that method will be assigned to the scope object rather than `Foo`. Here's a slightly more concrete example:

```
# app/models/club.rb
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  # name:string
  has_many :people
end

# app/models/person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  # club_id:integer, name:string, age:integer
  belongs_to :club

  def self.average_age
    # note that sum and count are being called on self, not Person
    sum('age') / count
  end
end
```

Let's see what happens when we create some clubs and people:

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)
irb(main):001:0> boys_club = Club.create(:name => 'boys')
irb(main):002:0> girls_club = Club.create(:name => 'girls')
irb(main):003:0> boys_club.people.create(:name => 'bob', :age => 20)
irb(main):004:0> boys_club.people.create(:name => 'joe', :age => 22)
irb(main):005:0> girls_club.people.create(:name => 'betty', :age => 30)
irb(main):006:0> Person.average_age
=> 24
irb(main):007:0> boys_club.people.average_age
=> 21
irb(main):008:0> Person.where("name LIKE 'b%'").average_age
=> 25
```

Comment: Aha! I didn't know about 'count' and I was thinking that I would need to do something like `self.each do { #stuff }` which obviously wasn't working. Thank you, that was very helpful!